# How can I know in mongodb if a field is a Date type?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

I'm working on a NodeJS+Mongodb app.

I've just inserted one record into mongodb using the console client:

```
db.user.save({myId:11111, myDate: ISODate("2012-04-30T00:00:00.000Z")})
```

The thing is, when I'm in node.js, I need to know if "myDate" field is really a Date type, in order to perform a data range query, etc.

I tried the following.

**1. on the mongo client console:**

```
typeof db.user.myDate --> It returns "Object"
db.user.myDate instanceof Date --> It returns "false"
```

**2. on my Nodejs code,**

I'm trying to get the type calling this `getTypeMembers` function. (obj comming from a db query)

```
exports.getTypeMembers = function(obj) {
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)

for(var _k in obj){
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[_k]) === '[object Array]' ) {
        obj[_k] = "Array";
    }
    else if(typeof(obj[_k])=="object"){
        obj[_k] = this.getTypeMembers(obj[_k]);
    }else{
        obj[_k] = typeof (obj[_k]);
    }
}
return obj;
```

};

What I get in this method is: `"String"`, when I need `"Date"`

Is there any other way to get some kind of `"Date"` result?

Comment: Are you adding docs with `myDate` as other types somewhere else?  Guess I'm confused on what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: No. I'm using always same structure. I understand your question, this is all because my webapp needs to get data from several collections, and collections are created dinamically by other apps, then... My webapp never knows which schema is behind each collection.  I hope it helps to clearify my idea.

Comment: What if you ran `db.user.myDate instanceof ISODate` instead? I think node.js translates `ISODate` directly within it's driver.

Comment: Is there any other way to get all types of a collection?

Comment: Your using a JSON parser, the date will have no object type, it will just be an Object...since JSON cannot house objects in their true form. There should be a sub field called $date within the date object, check for that.

Comment: when you call JSON stringify the date object gets changed to a string var a = {a:new Date()} using JSON.stringify(a) becomes '{"a":"2012-09-28T11:05:56.163Z"}'. you have to check against the actual bson types not the json stringified/parsed object that will reduce it to the basic javascript types supported by JSON (and Date is not one of them)

Comment: Thanks @christkv, I've noticed this. Now, I have same problem when checking the bson obj. Take a look to the nexts answers..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found my solution.

As @christkv said, once you call a JSON stringify, all original types are definitely lost.
So, thinking in this way, my method `getTypeMembers` works perfectly for me.

Notice that, obj parameter is coming from the DB, and also "_id" (mongodb identificator) is directly ommited in order to avoid problems when performs the recursive function:

```
exports.getTypeMembers = function(obj) {
    for(var _k in obj){
        if (_k =="_id") continue;
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[_k]) === "[object Number]"){
            obj[_k] = "Number";
        }else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[_k]) === "[object String]"){
            obj[_k] = "String";
        }else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[_k]) === "[object Date]"){
            obj[_k] = "Date";
        } else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[_k]) === '[object Array]' ) {
            obj[_k] = "Array";
        } else if(typeof(obj[_k])=="object"){
            obj[_k] = this.getTypeMembers(obj[_k]);
        } else{
            obj[_k]  = (typeof obj[_k])[0].toUpperCase() + (typeof obj[_k]).slice(1);
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

In the Mongo console part, I only can get the type doing the following:

```
db.user.find({},{myDate:1}).forEach(function(f) { print (f.myDate instanceof Date) } );
```

But If I do,

```
typeof db.user.myDate --> It returns "Object"
db.user.myDate instanceof Date --> It returns "false"
```

I still don't undertand why.

Comment: The last part, in Mongo console, returns false because db.user is of type collection and because of the way that console accesses objects (through magics like in PHP) the date field always comes back as a valid object but as a empty object with an std class type. so db.user will never be querable for its field type only the documents within the collection object when you do a cursor find.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the $type operator to query for fields of a specific type:

```
db.col.query({a: {$type: 9}})
```

9 being the number for the date type, see  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24type

As to determining the type inside node.js, it depends on your driver. I've used none, but it might be a specific prototype, like how ObjectId is. Maybe you could examine the object and look for the constructor name.

Comment: Sorry dude, but I don't get your idea.

What I do is get a record from the collection, and analyze field by field, and do specific things depending on the field type. My problem is I'm getting a String type instead of a date type.  I'm using node-mongodb-native driver.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by the use of

```
db.user.myDate
```

in your example.  Are you making this exact call on the Db object that node-mongodb-native is giving you?  If so, you should be getting undefined because you are not actually querying the database, but instead checking a property of the Db javascript object (a property that is in almost all certainty not there).

Could you post the code that you are running from the node.js process?  I tested out your code, using an identical shell insertion, and once I retrieved the doc from the database in node.js,

```
doc.myDate instanceof Date
```

returned true.

I also am not familiar with your application, but it seems ill-advised to me to be querying collections where you do not know the types of the data.  Why are you unsure what type of value the other applications are using for the myDate field?

**Edit:**

```
var coll = new mongo.Collection(client, 'user');
    coll.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    docs.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        console.log(doc.myDate instanceof Date);
    });
});
```

logs "true" for me when run in nodejs after an identical shell insert to yours.  What happens if you run it?

Comment: I did it, directly on the mongo client console. I did it again, and.. it's the same. It returns false, Why? I'm using v2.0.4

Comment: anyway, I'm going to add more information on my post, in order to clearify what I'm doing on the other part, nodejs

Comment: ` but it seems ill-advised to me to be querying collections whose schema you do not know.` isn't that kinda the point of MongoDBs schemaless design?

Comment: to some degree, but in production environments, it is good practice to know what fields, of what types, are in your database

Comment: Shelman, I don't understand. Reproducing your code, it returns false for me. (!?!?!!?)

Comment: My webapp is a data viewer, so it has to be able to show diferent type of data in different views. One of this view must be an intelligent data grid, where if it detects some date type, has to show a calendar selector for queries. Thins like that... hope it helps.

Comment: Going further, if I check the datatype in the mongo client console, I don't get true when asking for date type. The problem must be there, you guys, which version of mongo are you using?

Comment: @larrytron I personally still use 1.9 cos I never can seem to find the time to upgrade but personally you should be using 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your latest edit I believe I see the problem. You are parsing the document into JSON. Unlike BSON, JSON does not support the literal creation and storage of BSON objects. The `ISODate` object is a BSON data type.

So when you convert to JSON you actually lose this object.

You can solve this two ways:

- Don't convert to JSON until you have checked the field type
- Every object has properties. Date is no different, it should have a `$date` property (I believe) which you can check if `isset` to see if the field is of type date

Comment: Very interesting. I was going to change it, but I realized (you'll see in the next answer) that once I get the object from the database, I loose its type... I'll keep fightin'

Comment: @larrytron very interesting indeed, you shouldn't lose the object type in console. WHat are you using to pick out and iterate the documents in the console?

Comment: In the console, as I posted, `typeof db.user.myDate --> It returns "Object"
db.user.myDate instanceof Date --> It returns "false"`

Comment: But, If I do: `db.user.find({myDate: {$type: 9}})` It returns results, so, it means is date. Isn't it?

Comment: @larrytron Indeed it does, ah this is really confusing :S

Comment: @larrytron Yea what I meant by the console code is like what you have shown for your node.js code, the loop itself. Hang on I just realised you are trying to get the db.user.myDate type directly without pulling out the document from the db. This will return false all the time. Try doing a query for the saved user and then test that result.

Comment: yes! you're right. It works. `db.user.find({},{myDate:1}).forEach(function(f) { print (f.myDate instanceof Date) } );` returns true! Now, where should be the problem? I'm doing the same in nodejs, but I get 'False', should I have to change of driver?

Comment: @larrytron I must admit if you are using Shelmans code in node.js I am complettely stumped :(